# How to work with FILE, understanding a given code?

Tags: c

Given `infile` with `-1  -2  4  -7  11   -6  -13`

**Why the output is : 1 18 ?**

What does the line of `#define AD(x,y) abs(x-y)`? and why `AD` is needed?

```
#define AD(x,y) abs(x-y)
int main()
{
   FILE *fin, *fout;
   int arr[2], num;
   fin=fopen("infile","rb");
   fout=fopen("outfile","wb");
   while (fread(arr,sizeof(int),2,fin)==2)
   {
      num=AD(arr[0],arr[1]);
      fwrite(&num,sizeof(int), 1,fout);
      fseek(fin, sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR);
    }
  fclose(fin);
  fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: Insure "infile" has a binary representation of data and not textual.

Comment: Code reads (-1 -2), writes 1, skips 4, reads (-7 11), writes 18, skips -6, stops then a -13 is only 1 `int`

Comment: @chux why skeep 4 and write 18? in define line does AD stands for function that is abs(x-y)?

Comment: `fseek(fin, sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR);` advances the file position indicator by 1 `int`.

Comment: `abs()` is an integer absolute function call.  `|-7 - 11|` --> 18   (AD may mean "Absolute value of the Difference".)

Comment: @chux then why skips -6?

Comment: Same reason as skipping 4.

Comment: "Why the output is : 1 18" - if that isn't what you were expecting, what did you *think* it would be, and more importantly, *why* did you think that?

Answer (score 2):

I hope my answer will clarify most of the questions. Here are some changes to the code that explain some of the issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define AD(x,y) abs((x)-(y))

int val[] = {-1,  -2,  4,  -7,  11,   -6,  -13};
int cnt = sizeof(val)/sizeof(int);

// create the binary file with the specified numbers
void createInputFile()
{
    printf("Elems count = %d, sizeof(int) = %d\n", cnt, sizeof(int));
    FILE *f = fopen("infile", "wb");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {
        fwrite(&val[i], sizeof(int), 1, f);
        printf("%d ", val[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(f);
}

int main()
{
   FILE *fin, *fout;
   int arr[2], num;

   createInputFile();

   // example how to read back the numbers from the binary file (each time 2 numbers are read, if the list contains an odd
   // number of values, last one is not printed on screen because the while condition fails)
   /*fin=fopen("infile","rb");
   while (fread(arr,sizeof(int),2,fin)==2)
   {
      printf("-> %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
   }
   fclose(fin);
   */

   fin=fopen("infile","rb");
   fout=fopen("outfile","wb");
   while (fread(arr,sizeof(int),2,fin)==2)
   {
      printf("read %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
      num=AD(arr[0],arr[1]);
      fwrite(&num,sizeof(int), 1,fout);
      printf("computed %d which represents absolute value of (%d - %d)\n", num, arr[0], arr[1]);
      fseek(fin, sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR); // advance in the input file with sizeof(int) bytes, i.e. skip one int value
    }
  fclose(fin);
  fclose(fout);
  return 0;
}
```

The following

```
#define AD(x,y) abs((x)-(y))
```

is not a function, but a macrodefinition. Each time AD is found in the C code, it is replaced before compile time by abs. AD has 2 parameters, x and y. So AD(arr[0], arr[1]) will be replaced by abs((arr[0])-(arr[1])) which calculate the absolute value of the difference of the numbers. Note that each time a macrodefinition parameter is used, it is enclosed in parenthesis. Check the following:

```
AD(-2, -3)
```

will be replaced by abs(-2--3) if parenthesis are not used.

That is why it is strongly recommended to enclose with parenthesis each time parameters of macro are used.

When reading from a file either text file or binary (as in your example) the file pointer advance in the file with the number of values/bytes read. If you want to read all data (see commented while loop), there is no need to use additional fseek() calls. In your example calling

fseek(fin, sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR);

makes the file pointer advance one int position, after it already advanced 2 int positions because of

fread(arr,sizeof(int),2,fin)

So the result is correct, but you should state what exactly you expect the code to do.

The output of the above code is:

```
Elems count = 7, sizeof(int) = 4
-1 -2 4 -7 11 -6 -13
read -1 -2
computed 1 which represents absolute value of (-1 - -2)
read -7 11
computed 18 which represents absolute value of (-7 - 11)
```